# what is entries shared when update a tuple?

Tags: elixir

In official doc: https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html said:

> ```
> iex> tuple = {:a, :b, :c, :d}
> iex> put_elem(tuple, 2, :e)
> {:a, :b, :e, :d}
> ```
>
> Note that this applies only to the tuple itself, not its contents. For
>   instance, when you update a tuple, all entries are shared between the
>   old and the new tuple, except for the entry that has been replaced. In
>   other words, tuples and lists in Elixir are capable of sharing their
>   contents. This reduces the amount of memory allocation the language
>   needs to perform and is only possible thanks to the immutable
>   semantics of the language.

Is it mean: during change a tuple, the old and the new tuple using the same memory address for sharing data instead of allocate new memory just like in erlang?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this means is that the values in the tuple are not cloned.

For example, a small integer in Erlang occupies 1 word of memory and a tuple occupies 2 words + size of each element. If you now create a tuple `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}`, that's `2 + (2 + 3) + (2 + 3) = 12` words of memory.

If you now do `put_elem(tuple, 1, 4)` to create `{{1, 2, 3}, 4}`, it'll not clone the element at index 0 of of the original tuple (`{1, 2, 3}`), but only create a new tuple of size 2 + the integer `4`. Instead of an extra `2 + (2 + 3) + 1` words of memory, this update only uses `2 + 1` extra words of memory. The value `{1, 2, 3}` is shared among the two tuples.

[Source for the amount of memory used by different data structures in Erlang](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#id68680).

> just like in erlang?

Yes, a tuple in Elixir has the same semantics as a tuple in Erlang.